# How can I accredit my Russian kandidat nauk in biology to PhD in USA?

Tags: phd, united-states, biology, accreditation, russia

I have a kandidat nauk in biology from Russia, and as I know it's equivalent to a PhD degree outside post-Soviet countries.

My question is what do I need to do to accredit my degree in the USA? Which organization in the US do I have to contact?

Answer (score 7):

The US does not have a centralized system in this regard.  Each organization decides for itself how to consider your degree.  Anyone with international awareness who hires PhDs regularly should know that your degree is equivalent, but everyone makes their own judgement; there is no centralized body.